# Return list of objects as dictionary with keys as the objects id with django rest framerwork

Tags: python, django, api, dictionary, django-rest-framework

Currently, I have a ListAPIView that returns a list of object dictionaries:

```
[
  { id: 1, ...},
  { id: 2, ...},
  ...
]
```

I would like to change this to be formatted as a dictionary with the id as the key:

```
{
  "1": { id: 1, ...},
  "2": { id: 2, ...},
  ...
}
```

How do I customize the output in this way using Django Rest Framework? Currently I am doing the re-formatting client side, but I would like to do it server side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can implement the `to_representation` function in your Serializer.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    field1 = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    field2 = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    def to_representation(self, data):
        res = super(MySerializer, self).to_representation(data)
        return {res['id']: res}
        # or you can fetch the id by data directly
        # return {str(data.id): res}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can traverse each item and with a dict comprehension create your desired dictionary. For example:

```
>>> l = [{ "id": 1, "x": 4}, { "id": 2, "x": 3}]
>>> {v["id"]: v for v in l}
{1: {'x': 4, 'id': 1}, 2: {'x': 3, 'id': 2}}
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: current version available in a [Github project](https://github.com/claytondaley/drf-keyed-list) and PYPI (`pip install drf-keyed-list`)

Here's a general-purpose class that is bi-directional (vs. the read-only implementation above):

```
class KeyedListSerializer(ListSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        meta = getattr(self.child, 'Meta', None)
        assert hasattr(meta, 'keyed_list_serializer_field'), \
            "Must provide a field name at keyed_list_serializer_field when using KeyedListSerializer"
        self._keyed_field = meta.keyed_list_serializer_field

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # syntax is py3 only
        data = [{**v, **{self._keyed_field: k}} for k, v in data.items()]
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    def to_representation(self, data):
        response = super().to_representation(data)
        return {v.pop(self._keyed_field): v for v response}
```

For Py2, you need to make the `super` calls explicit and replace the indicated dictionary constructor.  You use it by assigning it to your `list_serializer_class` and selecting a `keyed_list_serializer_field` (i.e. the field used as the dict key):

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = KeyedListSerializer
        keyed_list_serializer_field = 'id'
```

The `keyed_list_serializer_field` should contain unique values; the above implementation doesn't check.