# Django rest framework: Listapiview return key:value pair dictionary than an array

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer: i am trying to add the key : value representation. After searching on stackoverflow, based on the answer at [Return list of objects as dictionary with keys as the objects id with django rest framerwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930401/return-list-of-objects-as-dictionary-with-keys-as-the-objects-id-with-django-res) i have overwritten the to_representation method.

```
class IngredientListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, data):
        res = super(IngredientListSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
        return {res['id']: res}
```

My view is:

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer
```

The output looks like this:

```
"results": [
        {
            "172": {
                "id": 172,
                "name": "rice sevai",
            }
        },
        {
            "218": {
                "id": 218,
                "name": "rocket leaves",
            }
        }
    ]
```

The output i am looking for is:

```
"results": {
        "172": {
            "id": 172,
            "name": "rice sevai",
        },
        "218": {
            "id": 218,
            "name": "rocket leaves",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code with a bit of modification should work, since the view calls the serializer `.to_representation()` once per item you can work on the result of the serializer. Though it will be probably better to use a generic view for your case

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientListSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = {obj['id']: obj for obj in serializer.data}
        return Response({'results': data})
```

Comment: res is not an array. Its an single dictionary

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi updated the code, I wasn't aware under the hood LIstAPIView calls the serializer once for every object in the queryset